# Effects of wood on UHF transmission

Tags: rf, materials, em

I have set up the following scenario in gprmax. From the results obtained using the software, I realized that when I increased the wood thickness the power received at the receiver increases instead of decreasing. Because if you had more wood in front of the transmitter it will impede the propagation. But from the simulations it kind of shows that the wood 'amplifies' the E and H field. Can someone explain why this is happening, the frequency is 915MHz?

The dielectric constant of wood is 5 and 2.4 for the plastic mount. Conductivity is 0 for both materials.

Or are the simulations wrong in terms of in reality the power should decrease has the thickness increases

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is focusing the beam. Can you tell from the software what properties are being assumed in the wood? Conductivity? Dielectric constant? Etc.

Comment: Sometimes a dielectric can act as a lens. But it will likely also change the resonant frequency of the antenna so in a real system, unless you re-tune the antenna, such a dielectric lens will not improve system performance.

Comment: @mkeith I have included the dielectric constant and conductivity. DIELECTRIC LENS! Please tell me more, this sounds very interesting!!!

Comment: @Transistor thank you. I have amended the title.

Comment: Optical lenses focus light because they have a different dielectric coefficient (we call it index of refraction but it is basically the same thing) than air. Basically, any dielectric placed close to an antenna will affect the resonant frequency of the antenna. This typically de-tunes the antenna, so that the VSWR is worse. Close means, what, I guess in the near field. I am not an expert on this stuff. Just know some basics. For visible wavelengths, the lens is basically always in the far field. But for RF it could be in the near field.

Comment: For sure the total power is not increasing. The only explanation is that the radiation pattern is being altered from isotropic to directional. If you do a little bit of ray tracing (newtonian optics) you will probably see why. Your system is simple enough.

Comment: @mkeith I just ran the sims and you are right when the material is thicker the material acts as a lens. Because instead of the e-field radiating outwards with a thinner material the e-field converges inside the wood like a focal point and due to superposition the e-field thus increases. This is so awesome!!

Comment: @mkeith or the moderator can assist me in closing this question due to it been answered by using mkeith in the comments.

Comment: Actually @joey, can you answer it yourself? I believe that is allowed even for people without much rep and you actually have a fair bit. You can post a picture of the setup with a thick dielectric and a short explanation. As long as you are able to post the answer you can then accept it. That is OK to accept your own answer.